# SqlServer default path

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have installed sql2008 on disk C, so the default data store path is on disk c, too. Now, I want to modify the default path so that I can store my database data on another disk, is there any solution? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
->SQL Server Management Studio 
->right click on the Server 
->property 
->Database settings 
->Database default location
```

Comment: Prince Jea,thank you for your help! I modified the default path, and when I created new database through SQL Server Management Studio, the new database's default path is what I seted, but when I create a new team project collection in TFS2010, the collection database is still created on the old path, what's wrong?